# Piping SVG file into ImageMagick

Tags: svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Sorry if this belongs on serverfault

I'm wondering what the proper way is to use an SVG(xml) string as standard input 
for a `"convert msvg:- jpeg:- 2>&1"` command (using linux)

Currently I'm just saving a temp file to use as input, 
but the data originates from an API in my case, so feeding
the string directly to the command would obviously be most efficient.

I appreciate everyone's help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
convert  -  output.jpg
```

**Example:**

```
convert  logo:  logo.svg
cat logo.svg | convert  -  logo.jpg
```

**Explanation:**

1. The example's first line creates an SVN file and writes it to disk. This is only a preparatory stop so that we can run the second line.
2. The second line is a *pipeline* of two commands: `cat` streams the bytes of the file to *stdout* (standard output).
3. The first line served only as preparation for the next command in the pipeline, so that this next command has something to read in.
4. This next command is `convert`.
5. The `-` character is a way to tell `convert` to read its input data not from disk, but from *stdin* (standard input).
6. So `convert` reads its input data from its *stdin* and writes its JPEG output to the file `logo.jpg`.
7. So my first command/line is similar to your step described as *'currently I'm just saving a temp file to use as input'*.
8. My second command/line does not use your API (I don't have access to it, do I?), but it demonstrates a different method to *'feeding a string directly to the command'*.
9. So the most important lesson is this: Whereever `convert` would usually read input from a file and where you would write the file's name on the commandline, you can replace the filename by `-` to tell `convert` it should read from *stdin*. (But you need to make sure that there is actually something offered on `convert`'s standard input which it can digest...)

Sorry, I can't explain better than this...

Comment: I'm sorry, Maybe I'm just new at this - but I don't get it. Where does my actual data string go?

Comment: Yeah ok, the method makes obvious sense now, just wanted to see why it does what it does, thanks for explaining!